# Is there a different meaning for ごちそうさま!

Tags: meaning

I have posted a "status" on Facebook:

> Dear santa, I would like for you to bring him for christmas

My boyfriend commented:

> Your Wish is my command!

And my Japanese manager (from our office) commented:

> ごちそうさま!!

In this case, what does `ごちそうさま!!` mean?  I think it is definitely not the meaning "Thanks for the meal".

So, are there any other meanings of `ごちそうさま!!`？

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is!
Primary use is the one you are already aware of.
ごちそうさま is also used after hearing something lovey-dovey like your boyfriend's "your wish is my command".

Comment: does it mean "So Sweet"?? :)

Comment: @NyeinNyeinChanChan, ごちそうさま has some in-built sarcasm that "so sweet" wouldn't necessarily have, kind of similar to "A bit more information than I needed to know" or "whoa, you two get a room" or something like that. Usually well-meant, of course.

Comment: Close to a sarcastic "Thanks for sharing!", perhaps.

Comment: It definitely is sarcastic: the 大辞泉 [says](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BE%A1%E9%A6%B3%E8%B5%B0%E6%A7%98?dic=daijisen) `皮肉を込めたりからかったりするあいさつの語`