# What is the usage/meaning of ご馳走さま (lovey-dovey)?

Tags: usage, meaning, etymology

Edict states that one of the meanings of [ご馳走さま](http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MUJ%E3%81%94%E9%A6%B3%E8%B5%B0%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE)  is *"used after hearing something lovey-dovey"*.

Does anyone know some examples whereby ご馳走さま is used this way? Specifically, how do we use "ご馳走さま" and when is it appropriate/inappropriate to use it?

Also, imagine we have this conversation between two people:

> A: Yesterday I kissed my baby.
>
> B: ご馳走さま

What exactly does B mean when he says ご馳走さま?

What will this "ご馳走さま" be when translated to English?

Comment: Sounds like it could be sarcastic(?) Neither my EJ or JJ dictionaries on Apple indicate this meaning. In case you have not tried, Space ALC does not give any examples either.

Comment: 明鏡 has as definition 3: `仲のいいさまを見せつけられたときや、のろけを聞かされたときなどに軽い皮肉やからかいの気持ちを込めていうことば。`

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13373/is-there-a-different-meaning-for-%e3%81%94%e3%81%a1%e3%81%9d%e3%81%86%e3%81%95%e3%81%be

Comment: Though I would comment that it does not have to be sarcastic. My host mother asked my wife how I met her and she was really enjoying hearing how and saying ごちそうさま in that context. I think the meaning is extensional from the food one as in "thanks for letting me hear that tidbit/morsel" (which is comprehensible in English as well). If I said, it'd be sarcasm along the lines of "too much information." but maybe I should say　吐きそうです or きもい.